# L1 sampling for sampling edges of a graph

Tags: graphs, data-structures, machine-learning, sampling, sketching

I am trying to sample the edges of an undirected graph using weights. The goal is to run a sparsification algorithm on the graph. I see the point that L1 norm is best for sparsification. Can someone tell me how exactly is L1 sampling performed on edges of a graph.

To be more precise with my query, Should we vectorize the indices of the graph and then apply L1 sampling on the sub vectors and perform sparse recovery?(correct me if I am wrong) or is there a better way?

Comment: What is L1 sampling?

Comment: http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~graham/pubs/papers/l0journal.pdf -  I was following this paper to understand l1 sampling. According to this paper, it is a sampling techniques used to sample near-uniformly ,from
the support set of a dynamic multiset, and I was using sparsification algorithm in this paper - https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mcgregor/papers/12-dynamic.pdf (page 10)

Comment: It seems that edges should be sampled proportional to their weight. If the total weight is $W$, then an edge with weight $w$ should be sampled with probability $w/W$.

Comment: Okay, I see that, but, this sampling technique is performed on stream of data, not necessarily graph streams(correct me if I am wrong). Then would the stream on which we implement the L1 sampling contain indexes of the edges?

Comment: Yes, that's an equivalent formulation, though I disagree that you can only sample from streams. Pollsters sample voters from the population without using any streams of any sort.

Comment: Okay, from what I understand, L1 sampling is majorly done on dynamic multisets which means that values in the set need not be unique. However, indexes(mostly, maybe I am missing something here?) are usually unique. So in what way does it make sense to perform this technique. I am currently using a social network graph which is undirected. Does this affect anything?

Comment: L1 sampling is what I wrote above. You can do it "offline", or in a streaming fashion. But the idea of the streaming formulation is to obtain the same result as the offline variant, but using very little memory.